# Spanning Subgraphs of random sizes with probabilities on edges

Tags: graphs-and-networks, probability-or-statistics, random

I need a way of taking some graph G and obtaining a spanning subset of G where each edge $e_i$ has some probability $P_i$ of being in the subgraph. So the size of the edge sets of each random subgraph would also be random, up to the given probabilities. I've looked at existing Mathematica commands, and most random sampling functions would seem to require that I specify the number of edges that will be in my subgraph. And this is not what I'm after.

I'm aware of the Subgraph function, but this doesn't seem to get me the desired results either, since it asks the user to input the edges/vertices so that it can construct the explicit subgraph.

What do y'all recommend?

Comment: Could you add an example?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retain each edge in a graph `g` with probability `p`, you can use:

```
sample[list_, p_] := 
 Pick[list, UnitStep[p - RandomReal[1, Length[list]]], 1]

Graph[VertexList[g], sample[EdgeList[g], p]]
```

If you also want to retain the various edge/vertex properties the graph may have, you can use `IGTakeSubgraph` from [the IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM/).

Of course this may not produce a connected graph, but you did not ask for that. The `IGRandomSpanningTree` functions from IGraph/M may be of interest: it samples the spanning trees of a graph uniformly. Note that just adding more graph edges to a spanning tree randomly will not achieve the *uniform* sampling of connected spanning subgraphs.